# Множественные callbak`и activity с binded service. Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-binder

Добры день

В общем есть есть `service`, который хранит в себе множество объектов (сигналов, например показаний датчиков)

```
class SignalsDataService : Service() {

    val signals: MutableMap<Int, SignalChannel> = ConcurrentHashMap()

    /*бла бла бла
     ..... 
    */

}
```

Во время привязки (bindService) службы к `Activity` я хотел осуществлять
динамическое создание конкретный view для каждого сигнала и связать сигналы через `callback'и` на обновление конкретного view

Но если сигналов будет 100 например. Уже не знаю насколько такая реализация хороша. Особенно если `Activity` свернется, получится, что `view` помрут (как я понимаю)

Как в таком случае лучше всего обновлять множество view в `activity` когда данные идут из сервиса ?

Comment: как вариант  попробуйте сервис связать с базой данных, и уже с нее создавать активити..